# Why can I not use predefined constants in .rc file?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I want to make sure one cannot mix up 64 and 32 bit version of my DLL file. This is why I defined following preprocessor constant in the project properties:

[image: image description]

In my `.rc` file, I have these lines:

```
#ifdef x64 
  #define MY_PRODUCT_NAME = "My file 64bit"
#else
  #define MY_PRODUCT_NAME = "My file 32bit"
#endif
```

I want to use these constants in resource block below:

```
BEGIN
    BLOCK "StringFileInfo"
    BEGIN
        BLOCK "000904b0"
        BEGIN
            VALUE "CompanyName", "SOMENAME"
            VALUE "FileDescription", "WHAT THIS FILE IS"
            VALUE "FileVersion", "1.0.0.1"
            VALUE "InternalName", "file.dll"
            VALUE "LegalCopyright", "Don't sell it pls"
            VALUE "ProductName", MY_PRODUCT_NAME
        END
```

On the line containing `MY_PRODUCT_NAME`, I get this compiler error:

```
1>  
1>StopThat.rc(58): error RC2133: unexpected value in value data
1>  
1>  
1>StopThat.rc(58): error RC2132: expected VALUE, BLOCK, or END keyword
1>
```

This makes me real angry, because that's **[exactly what microsoft does in their documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa381058%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#code-snippet-3)**.

Am I doing something wrong? I guess I am, so what is it?

Comment: Um, no it isn't. You're missing a crucial part: of `#define VER_FILEVERSION_STR         "3.10.349.0\0"` - see the NULL character terminating the string? You're missing it in all of your string values, BTW.

Comment: The string values were defined and generated by visual studio 2012. I'll add it to the constant though.

Comment: Now I see even more crucial problem. There's no ` = ` in `define`.

Comment: Your next to last paragraph says **that's exactly what microsoft does in their documentation**, and I pointed out that it isn't. Also, which line is line #58 (the one indicated in both error messages as being the problem line)? You've definitely not included 58 lines of text, so it's impossible to count to identify it from here. But I think you're right - the *=* is in fact the culprit.

Comment: @KenWhite I'm not sure why are you posting that bold text. I already said I see the difference, no need to shout at me - which is what bold text sounds like. I also specifically said that the error is thrown for the first occurrence of the constant - which probably happened due to both = character and missing terminating `\0`.

Comment: I quoted back *exactly what you posted*; I wasn't shouting at you, and I apologize if it seemed that way. You emphasized it, and I provided the same emphasis.Once again, my apologies if I offended you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the code you posted is exactly equal to the code you tried to compile, I would say it might be that you are two END statements short of complete scoping, also I have never seen an equals sign in a #define statement.

To be sure though, I am no expert when it comes resource files.

Answer (score 1):

Its because you are using an assignment operator in your macro definition, remove the "=" from your defines:

```
#ifdef x64 
  #define MY_PRODUCT_NAME "My file 64bit"
#else
  #define MY_PRODUCT_NAME "My file 32bit"
#endif
```